# Check if item already exists in list<list>

Tags: c#

```
List<list> ListA = new List<list>();
ListA.Add(new list() { Date = PlayerDate, Name = PlayerName, Scorer = PlayerLe });
lvTeamA.ItemsSource = 

    public class list
    {
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Scorer { get; set; }
    }
```

How can I check if `PlayerName` already exists in `ListA` so I can prevent adding the data again?

Comment: You should consider to rename your class, `list` is a variable-name of a collection type, your class stores a single Player. So a more appropriate name would be `Player`. If you want to check if your list contains already a given player you should override `Equals` + `GetHashCode`.

Comment: Check - http://www.dotnetperls.com/list-contains, http://www.dotnetperls.com/iequalitycomparer

Comment: thank you for the extra info, I am new to this, wish I could upvote..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use .Any() method.

```
if(ListA.Any(l => l.Name == "player name")) {
   // it's already added...
}
```